# What do dots on the tempo's equal sign mean?

Tags: notation, tempo

What do the dots on the tempo's equal sign mean in this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This means "approximately equal to". I found this with a quick Google search. [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/isoamsr.html) is an example of a webpage confirming the meaning of this symbol. I must confess, I prefer to use "c.", the abbreviation for [circa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa), in metronome markings. Here's an example:

[image]

I've also seen the "wiggly" equal sign used in metronome marks. It's the top one at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Approximately_equal) webpage (which shows quite a few different symbols for "approximately equal to").

I must confess I hadn't seen the marking in your question, though, so I've learnt something today...

Comment: How does this affect the way the music is played?

Comment: Just means the tempo marking is approximate; you can play a little faster or slower than this tempo. I would argue it's a bit unnecessary really, as it is rarely that important to play exactly at a specific tempo. ***Unless***, of course, you are playing along with an existing recording, or with a backing track or live electronics, for instance. In which case it should be pretty obvious that you need to play at an exact tempo. Or if playing film music, I guess...

Comment: Play it at roughly that tempo, possibly a bit faster, possibly a bit slower. Your tempo may (and probably should) vary a bit to take into account the resonance of the room and other factors. This approximation symbol, btw, is commonly used in the Far East.